# Setting a minimum width for responsive Bootstrap layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I would like my Bootstrap layout to not act responsive when the width is 768px or smaller. You can view my current application HTML / CSS here, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXdYNa. I have had to make some changes to some of the standard Bootstrap styles so it might make things a bit more tricker.

Does anyone have any tips on how to achieve this by using CSS overrides, similar to what I have done here:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    padding-left: 250px;
    padding-top: 89px;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind accepting an answer?

Answer (score 3):

How about just giving .container-fluid a min-width with 768px?

**EDIT:**

Adding the following worked for me:

```
.container-fluid {
  min-width: 768px;
}

.main {
    padding-left: 250px;
    padding-top: 89px;
}
```

A min-width in combination with removing the media query which is around your .main should work.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwmEXr

Comment: Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Please look at my answer again.

Answer (score -1):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .main {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
  } 
}
```